# Can't return data to postman

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get data from the database and return it to postman. In debug mode I can see that there is some data, but by some reasom I don't see it in postman.

[image]

[image]

```
    public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> GetProductComparsionByListId(int listId)
    {
        var comparsionList = _dbContext.ProductsComparsion.Include(z => z.ProductsToCompare).FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == listId);

        if (comparsionList == null)
            return null;

        var category = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == comparsionList.CategoryId);


        var tmp = new ProductComparsionVM
        {
            ProductsToCompare2 = comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.ToList()
        };

        return tmp;
    }

public class ProductComparsionVM
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<int> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }

    public List<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare2 { get; set; }
}
```

There is other fields, which I can get in postman if comment `ProductsToCompare2 = ..`

**Edit 1**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductComparsionByListId([FromBody] ProductComparsionVM comparsion)
    {
        return Json(await _productRepo.GetProductComparsionByListId(comparsion.ListId));
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you've spelled "comparison" wrong in multiple places in your code. Might want to fix it.

Comment: How did you return it and serialize in a controller?

Comment: @mason Thanks, I will fix it

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Added code from controller

Comment: What is the response status?

Comment: @phuzi It is "200 OK". For other fields it works fine, but if I uncomment `ProductsToCompare2`, then it don't return anything and status is still "200 OK"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending the parameter `listId` as method parameter the value in PostMan can be entered as `form-data`.

[image]

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer!